# How do i store and load trained data in deeplearning4j?

Tags: deeplearning4j

deeplearning4j : How can I store/save a trained model on persistence level and load it back when an ad-hoc request comes to evaluate the deep learning model?

```
        DataNormalization normalizer = new NormalizerStandardize();
        normalizer.fit(trainingData);           //Collect the statistics (mean/stdev) from the training data. This does not modify the input data
        normalizer.transform(trainingData); 

        //run the model
        MultiLayerNetwork model = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
        model.init();
        model.setListeners(new ScoreIterationListener(100));

        for( int i=0; i<epochs; i++ ) {
            model.fit(trainingData);
        }
```

**I need to store the trained model. How can I do this? With which Api?**

```
        //evaluate the model on the test set
        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(3);
        INDArray output = model.output(testData.getFeatures());

        eval.eval(testData.getLabels(), output);
        log.info(eval.stats());
```

Answer (score 3):

With the [ModelSerializer](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/deeplearning4j/util/ModelSerializer.html)

You can write/read it like this

```
ModelSerializer.writeModel(modelToSave, "location", true);

...

MultiLayerNetwork model = ModelSerializer.restoreMultiLayerNetwork("location");
```